# My I phone 6 some contacts not displayed with contact name only contact no displayed

Tags: ios

I purchased a new iPhone 6 and have problem with importing my contacts. I imported all SIM contacts to phone but all of my SIM contacts not displayed, some contacts displayed without name.

I have tried many times with the same result. I checked my SIM contacts with another android mobile, it correctly displayed all contacts with contact names.

How can I Import my all contacts with names to my I phone?

Comment: What resources do you have available? Can you connect that SIM to other phones / other OS or a dedicated transfer device like cellubrite? Is it worth paying for help or is this just to save you from manually typing the missing data after putting the SIM in the old phone? Also - how many records are you seeking to transfer. 10, 100, 1000?

Answer (score 1):

If you can see them correctly on android, it may be easier to export them from there to .vcf, .csv or whatever format it offers and trying to import them back to your iPhone.

If you have a Gmail account, uploading them into it or associating them to it will probably be a relatively easy solution. You can add your Gmail account to your iPhone and use it to sync your contacts.